# Compare different types of ArrayList

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Initially I had one `ArrayList<Book>` perfectly functional. But, I wanted to show my list of books in a PopUp Menu, for this `AlertDialog.Builder` with `setMultiChoiceItems` was the suitable choice that I made. So I had to convert this `ArrayList` into a `CharSequence`. So far so good. The problem comes now: I want to show the option(s) previously selected in a RecyclerView, (already coded), but I'll need those getters and setters of my object. How can this be solved?

(EDIT)

```
fab.setOnClockListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final ArrayList<Integer> bookSel = new ArrayLis();
        ArraList<Book> arrayBook = (ArrayList<Book>) bd.getBooks();

        final CharSequence[] cs = new CharSequence[arrayBook.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayBook.size(); i++) {
            cs[i] = String.valueOf(arrayBook.get(i));
        }

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder (getActivity());
        alertBuilder.setTitle("Books")
         .setMultiChoiceItems(cs, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    bookSel.add(which);
                } else if (bookSel.contains(which)) {
                    bookSel.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                }
            }
         });
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onCLick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ArrayList<String> listAux = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < bookSel.size(); i++) {
                    listAux.add(String.valueOf(cs[bookSel.get(i)]));
                }
                BookAdapter adp = new BookAdapter(getActivity(),/*send the object<Book>*/);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adp);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] bookListAlert;
boolean[] checkedBooks;
ArrayList<String> bookNames = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Book> bookDetails = new ArrayList<Book>();
bookDetails = bookList.getlistOfBooks();
checkedColors = new boolean[bookDetails.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < bookDetails.size(); i++) {
        checkedBooks[i] = false;
        strBookName= bookDetails.get(i).getBookName();
        bookNames.add(strBookName);
    }
        bookListAlert = bookNames.toArray(new String[access.size()]);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            BookScreen.this);

    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(bookListAlert, checkedColors,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(
                            AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
                    boolean isCheckedBooks = true;
                    for (i = 0; i < checkedBooks.length; i++) {
                        if (!checkedBooks[i]) {
                            isCheckedBooks = false;
                        } else {
                            isCheckedBooks = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isCheckedBooks) {

                        ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(
                                AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(
                                true);

                    } else {
                        ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(
                                AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setEnabled(
                                false);
                    }
                }
            });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Books");
    builder.setPositiveButton("DONE",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
    )};
```

Comment: If you share your code it will be easy to help you. Thanks